# Why extract doesn't import negative indices?

Tags: php, extract

I was playing with extract method and I noticed that it doesn't work on negative indices.

Let's take this code snippet as an example :

```
<?php

$arr = [0 => 'faa', 1 => 'fee', -2 => 'foo'];
$result = extract($arr, EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID, 'var');

echo $var_-2; // Absolutely wrong

?>
```

So I tried to do this :

```
echo ${'var_-2'} // Notice: Undefined variable: var_-2
```

Then since extract as documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

> Returns the number of variables successfully imported into the symbol table

I did this :

```
echo $result; // 2
```

It seems extract didn't import `-2` into the symbol table in the first place.

What exactly is the reason since documentation says nothing about this behavior?

Comment: From docs.http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php.  `Checks each key to see whether it has a valid variable name.`

Comment: Can you even assign `extract` to a variable?

Comment: it didn't say valid keys but valid variable name. `-` is obviously invalid character for a variable name.

Comment: extract is evil, dont use it.

Comment: @FatalError Interesting! I actually did not know that.

Comment: imo, the only time to use it would be to extract out an associative array into a views scope. not into global scope. and never with a numeric array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `-` is not a valid symbol according to [php variable naming conventions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

Following quote shamelessly copied from docs:

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

```
// var_-2 results in 0 because of -
var_dump(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$/", "var_-2")); // int(0)
// var_2 is a valid identifier so result is 1
var_dump(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$/", "var_2")); // int(1)
```